# Show that all the characteristic roots of a dispersion matrix of a random variable are non-negative

Tags: self-study, multivariate-analysis, eigenvalues

Show that all the characteristic roots of a dispersion matrix of a random variable are non-negative.

$$\begin{vmatrix} \sigma_{11}-\lambda & \sigma_{12} &  \cdots & \sigma_{1p}\\ \sigma_{21} & \sigma_{22}-\lambda & \cdots & \sigma_{2p} \\  \vdots & \vdots  & & \vdots\\ \sigma_{p1} & \sigma_{p2} &\cdots & \sigma_{pp}-\lambda \end{vmatrix}=0$$ Hence how can I show that  $\lambda$ is non-negative. Please help.

Comment: Hint: what are the implications of the characteristic roots being non-negative? Try to find a way to utilize that $y'\Sigma y=y'E(X-\mu)(X-\mu)'y=Var(y'(X-\mu))$.

Comment: @MånsT:please explain the implication and how I proceed

Comment: Same hint, different language: the characteristic roots of that matrix are all variances of linear combinations of components of the variable.

Comment: @Ranabir: have a look at the definition of [positive-semidefinite matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Negative-definite.2C_semidefinite_and_indefinite_matrices)

Comment: I would have given the same hint as MansT.  I think if you look at the properties of positive semidefinite matrices you might find a theorem about them that will answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

$(\Sigma-\lambda I)y=0$ The characteristic Equation

$ =>y'(\Sigma-\lambda I)y=0$ Pre-Multipling $y'$

$=>y'\Sigma y=y'\lambda y$

$=>\lambda=\frac{y'\Sigma y}{y'y}=\frac{Var(y'(X-\mu))}{\sum y_i^2} \geq 0$ Asuming $\sum y_i^2\neq 0$

Comment: Is this correct or I need to modify this.Please help

Comment: That looks correct!